# How to re-run all failed tasks in Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have a Apache Airflow DAG with tens of thousands of tasks and after a run, say a handful of them failed.

I fixed the bug that caused some tasks to fail and I would like to re-run ONLY FAILED TASKS. 
This `SO` post suggests using the GUI to "clear" failed task:

[How to restart a failed task on Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270820/how-to-restart-a-failed-task-on-airflow)

This approach works if you have a handful number of failed tasks.

I am wondering if we can bypass the GUI and do it problematically, through command line something like:

```
airflow_clear_failed_tasks dag_id execution_data
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following command to clear only failed tasks:

```
airflow clear [-s START_DATE] [-e END_DATE] --only_failed dag_id
```

Documentation: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#clear

Answer (score 10):

The command to clear only failed tasks was updated. It is now (Airflow 2.0 as of March 2021):

```
airflow tasks clear [-s START_DATE] [-e END_DATE] --only-failed dag_id
```

Comment: use the option as --only_failed or -f

Comment: According to [the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html), date format when using this command is `YYYY-MM-DD`